# Why does list.Contains(x) not find x when list contains x,y,z

Tags: c#

ACCEPTED THE FIRST COMPLETE ANSWER GIVEN.

THANKS TO ALL WHO RESPONDED!

---

I'm new to C# and Visual Studio so forgive me if this is an elementary question.

```
if (!exceptions.Contains(accountNodeID))
{
     dummyTotals.Add(accountNodeID, accountNodeTotal);
}
```

- **exceptions** is a `List<string>`
- **accountNodeID** is a `string`
- **dummyTotals** is a `Dictionary<string, int>`

If **exceptions** consists of only one element, *Contains* DOES recognize when **accountNodeID** is in **exceptions**.

If **exceptions** consists of 2+ elements, *Contains* DOES NOT recognize when **accountNodeID** is in **exceptions**.

Screenshots of Visual Studio debugger [which SO won't allow me to post here because I had to create a new account :( ]:

- [**accountNodeID** is in **exceptions**, but is added to **dummyTotals** anyway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIszU.png).
- [but that doesn't happen when **exceptions** contains only one element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3D2g.png).

Can anyone tell me the following?

1. Why *Contains* doesn't recognize that **accountNodeID** is one among several elements in **exceptions** -- my code certainly looks like all of the examples I can find, so far as I can tell
2. How to prevent **accountNodeID** from being added to **dummyTotals** when it is among several elements in **exceptions**

Very happy to provide additional relevant info, as needed! Thanks very much!!!

---

**EDIT**

Thank you for the info that has been supplied already. I'm looking over it now. For the record, the following is how the list is being created (iterating over nodes in an XML file and using *Add*).

```
        List<string> dummyList = new List<string>();

        while (exceptionsIterator.MoveNext())
        {
            exceptions.Add(exceptionsIterator.Current.Value); 

        }
```

I thought this was adding list elements rather than concatenating values onto a string.

---

**EDIT**

See my final comment on the answer for the ultimate resolution to this problem.

Comment: We need to see your code for creating `exceptions` and `dummyTotals`. A Minimum Viable Example should help us. Soon as you can provide the code, the question will go into the re-open queue.

Comment: In your first screenshots, `"139"` is *not* an element of `exceptions`. The string `"541 139 434"` is.

Comment: He already provide the code actually.and the reason it pretty clear.

Comment: @Selman22: Nominate for reopening then. I too think the question can be well answered with the information provided; I've described the reason for the observed issue in my comment.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper yeah I was just going to write an answer.but question is closed before I press the button :)

Comment: Try this if(!exceptions.Any(s=>s.Contains(accountNodeID)))

Comment: oops i didnt refreshed the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your debugging screenshot shows that exceptions only contains one element: "541 139 434"

[image]

So the fault must lie in how exceptions is populated.

When you add to a `List<string>`, you do so by calling `.Add(string)`.
I suspect there is code like:

```
List<string> exceptions = new List<string>(String.Join(" ", accountNodeIds));
```

This is NOT the way to populate a list. Instead:

```
List<string> exceptions = new List<string>(accountNodeIds);
```

or

```
exceptions.AddRange(accountNodeIds);
```

or

```
foreach (string accountNodeId in accountNodeIds) {
    exceptions.Add(accountNodeId);
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how my *Add* in the while loop is different than your *Add* in the foreach? See edit in original post.

Comment: Based on your code, I would assume because exceptionsIterator only contains `"541 139 434"`. Where does it come from?

Comment: THANK YOU! Yes, I came to the same conclusion and thus realized I was selecting a group of nodes at once with all three values instead of properly iterating over each node. You also correctly pointed out that the var only contained one string value instead of three, which I should have seen right away. Thanks again!

Comment: It's my distinguished pleasure :)

Answer (score 1):

[`List.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) just loooks if the object inside equals another object, in case of string it looks if the whole string matches. You are looking for a substring since "541 139 434" is not the same as "139".

You can use `String.Contains` with `Enumerable.Any`:

```
if (!exceptions.Any(e => e.Contains(accountNodeID)))
{
     dummyTotals.Add(accountNodeID, accountNodeTotal);
}
```

You could also check if one of the "words" in the string (separated by white-space) is the one you're looking for, therefore use `String.Split`:

```
if (!exceptions.Any(e => e.Split().Contains(accountNodeID)))
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it looks for the exact match.Instead you should use `Any`, in order to check whether any of your elements *Contains* your `accountNodeId`:

```
if (!exceptions.Any(x => x.Contains(accountNodeID))
```

Or  don't do this.Store your `Ids` seperately into your `List`.Each item should contain one `Id`.Then you can use `Contains` and you will get the expected result.